# How to specify which Azure Service Bus Topic to use with MassTransit

Tags: c#, azureservicebus, masstransit, azure-servicebus-topics

I've tried using MassTransit to publish a message to a topic named `events` in an Azure Service Bus. I have problems configuring MassTransit to use my predefined topic `events`, instead it creates a new topic named by the namespace/classname for the message type. So I wonder how to specify which topic to use instead of creating a new one.

This is the code I've tested with:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MassTransit;
using MassTransit.AzureServiceBusTransport;
using Microsoft.ServiceBus;

namespace PublisherNameSpace
{
    public class Publisher
    {
        public static async Task PublishMessage()
        {
            var topic = "events";
            var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(
                cfg =>
                {
                    var azureServiceBusHost = cfg.Host(new Uri("sb://<busname>.servicebus.windows.net"), host =>
                    {
                        host.OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
                        host.TokenProvider =
                            TokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider(
                                "RootManageSharedAccessKey",
                                "<key>"
                            );
                    });

                    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(azureServiceBusHost, topic, e =>
                    {
                        e.Consumer<TestConsumer>();
                    });
                });

            await bus.Publish<TestConsumer>(new TestMessage { TestString = "testing" });
        }
    }

    public class TestConsumer : IConsumer<TestMessage>
    {
        public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<TestMessage> context)
        {
            return Console.Out.WriteAsync("Consuming message");
        }
    }

    public class TestMessage
    {
        public string TestString { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to consume from a specific topic, create a subscription endpoint instead of a receive endpoint, and specify the topic and subscription name in the configuration.

The simplest form is shown in the unit tests:

https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/tests/MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.Tests/Subscription_Specs.cs

Comment: Thanks, that should do it. However, in one of my services I'm restricted to MassTransit 3.3.5 (due to old Newtonsoft.Json) where the SubscriptionEndpoint method is not introduced. Do you if it's possible to specify which topic to use in that version too?

Comment: It is not supported by that version.

Comment: Updated. Of course, it will change again once v7 is released.

Answer (score 14):

The accepted answer clears up the subscription side:

```
cfg.SubscriptionEndpoint(
    host,
    "sub-1",
    "my-topic-1",
    e =>
    {
        e.ConfigureConsumer<TestConsumer>(provider);
    });
```

For those wondering how to get the bus configuration right on the publish side, it should look like:

```
cfg.Message<TestMessage>(x =>
{
    x.SetEntityName("my-topic-1");
});
```

You can then call publish on the bus:

```
await bus.Publish<TestMessage>(message);
```

Thanks to @ChrisPatterson for [pointing this out to me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57593881/correct-way-to-publish-and-subscribe-to-an-explicit-service-bus-topic-with-masst)!

Comment: I don't know why the official documentation is not this clear. I find it very difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to send to an Azure Service Bus Topic using the **_sendEndpointProvider.GetSendEndpoint(new Uri("topic:shape"));** where... "shape" is the topic name.

```
public class MassTransitController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<MassTransitController> _logger;
    private readonly ISendEndpointProvider _sendEndpointProvider;

    public MassTransitController(ILogger<MassTransitController> logger, ISendEndpointProvider sendEndpointProvider)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _sendEndpointProvider = sendEndpointProvider;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        try
        {
            var randomType = new Random();
            var randomColor = new Random();

            var shape = new Shape();
            shape.ShapeId = Guid.NewGuid();
            shape.Color = ShapeType.ShapeColors[randomColor.Next(ShapeType.ShapeColors.Count)];
            shape.Type = ShapeType.ShapeTypes[randomType.Next(ShapeType.ShapeTypes.Count)];

            var endpoint = await _sendEndpointProvider.GetSendEndpoint(new Uri("topic:shape"));
            await endpoint.Send(shape);

            return Ok(shape);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

I also was able to get a .NET 5 Worker Consumer working with code like this... where the subscription "sub-all" would catch all shapes.. I'm going to make a blog post / git repo of this.

```
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddMassTransit(x =>
                {
                    x.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) =>
                    {
                        cfg.Host("Endpoint=sb://******");

                        cfg.SubscriptionEndpoint(
                            "sub-all",
                            "shape",
                            e =>
                        {
                            e.Handler<Shape>(async context =>
                            {
                                await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Shape Received: {context.Message.Type}");
                            });

                            e.MaxDeliveryCount = 15;
                        });
                    });
                });

                services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
            });
```